# How to safely quit pyqt application python

Tags: python, multithreading, class, pyqt5

I have a `pyqt5` project. I am starting the window in full screen mode. It is working but because it full screen so I cannot click on `x` button to close it so I have to press `alt-f4` to close it. It works fine but now I have another class running in the project due to which when I press `alt-f4`, it closes the window but still looks the thread didnt closed due to which it stays in the terminal. Below is the code:

```
class RecognizeFaceInFrame(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.get_face_name = False
        self.stop_face_thread = False

    def recognize_face_frame(self):
        try:
            if self.get_face_name:
                #SOME CODE
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occurred in recognize face {}".format(e))

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_face_thread:
            self.recognize_face_frame()

class TRIANGLE(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # SOME CODE
        self.showFullScreen()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.view_cam)
        self.timer.start(20)
        self.frame_count = 0

        self.face_recog_thread = RecognizeFaceInFrame()  
        self.face_recog_thread.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.face_recog_thread.stop_face_thread = True

    def view_cam(self):
        # SOME CODE


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('Windows')
main_window = TRIANGLE()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have a class `RecognizeFaceInFrame` which I am initializing in `__init__` in `TRIANGLE` class. Function  `recognize_face_frame` will start execution if we set `get_face_name` to `True`. If we set `stop_face_thread` to `True`, this thread will close automatically and thus I have put this in `__del__` of `TRAINGLE` but when I am pressing `alt-f4` it doesn't closes. Can anyone please help me understand what I should do here to safely close all the threads and application. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [closeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QCloseEvent.html)?

Classes inheriting Qt modules are removed by Qt's own [garbage collector](https://machinekoder.com/how-to-not-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-using-python-qt/) - at least link says so. Therefore, UI Object is not immediately deleted.

Change PySide2 to PyQt and try this. Function closeEvent will run as soon as you hit alt+f4. Until then, thread will keep printing out message to console.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtGui import QCloseEvent
from threading import Thread
import sys
import time


class TestThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stop_thread = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_thread:
            print("I'm alive!")
            time.sleep(1)

        print("Dead! Not a big surprise.")


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.test_thread = TestThread()
        self.test_thread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event:QCloseEvent):
        self.test_thread.stop_thread = True



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result:

> I'm alive!
>   I'm alive!
>   I'm alive!
>   Dead! Not a big surprise.
>
> Process finished with exit code -1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `aboutToQuit` signal from QApplication. Just connect it to your cleanup methods. [See docs.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit)